# When should I use connected RowSet and when - disconnected?

Tags: java, jdbc, rowset

I have read this intersting article about rowset

http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2014/04/Connected-vs-disconnected-rowsetprovider-rowsetfactory-and-rowset-JDBC-Java.html

I realized that we have 2 types of RowSet:

1. connected  (`JdbcRowset`)
2. disconnected (`JoinRowSet`, `CachedRowSet`, `FilteredRowSet` and `WebRowSet`)

I understand difference between these `RowSet` types but I have misunderstanding about aims of creation two types of `RowSet`. It relates with performance issues?

And after first question answer I want to know why only `JdbcRowset` is connected and rest `Rowset` inheritors are disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

From your source:
*1) Disconnected database connected to the database only when they want to read or write, a(...) on the other hand, Connected database **keep JDBC connection alive all time**.*

So why would we waste resources => performance issue.